# Exclude Rows in Dataframe Based on Pattern (Regex?)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a data frame with GPS Latitude coordinates. I want to EXCLUDE rows that have the coordinates formatted a certain way.

Correct:

`[39, 16, 1031971/156250]`

I want to exclude the ones (rows) with formatting as below:

`[39, 8050139/500000, 0]`

I tried a couple things using regular expressions with no luck. Any ideas? Sometimes the number of digits before and after the slash will differ by 1 or 2. Example is `8050139/500000` and `8050156/4000` in some rows.

The column is titled `GPS GPSLatitude`.

Comment: Is your data in a list? Or is it in a string with that format?

Comment: It is a string with that format located in a column in a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/HecK0J/1) - `,.+\/.+,` - just exclude anything which has a match. The regex looks for anything between two commas which has a `/` in it. The first value doesn't have two commas surrounding characters containing a `/`.

```
[39, 16, 1031971/156250]  
# no match
```

For your second value, which does:

```
[39, 8050139/500000, 0]
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  match
```

In actual application, use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) and pass `na=False` as one of your parameters. I would subset like so:

```
df[~df['gps'].str.contains(r',.+\/.+,', regex=True, na=False)]
```

Comment: I tried this: ````patternDel = ",.+\/.+,"```` and then ````filter = df['GPS GPSLatitude'].str.contains(patternDel)```` and it returned none.

Comment: `filter` contains a series of boolean and `np.nan` values, not literally nothing. What are you actually doing?

Comment: I ran this on my dataframe: ````df[df['GPS GPSLatitude'].str.contains(r',.+\/.+,', regex=True, na=False)]```` and it returned no records. I am thinking the ````regex```` is not working. But your logic makes perfect sense though....

Comment: Oh sorry, you want to invert the series `~` so that it only selects elements that do **not** match. What you ran implies that there are no wrongly matching values.

Comment: Gotcha. I ran that and it returned all records and didn't remove the ones we don't want.

Comment: Hm, but the ````regex```` makes sense when I tested it. But it's not picking up the pattern and removing it.

Comment: So the data doesn't match the expected pattern. Post your data.